# Is there a way to conditionally apply CSS based on something other than class?

Tags: css

We have roughly 20 error pages, and we are gradually redesigning each.

The parent element, with a class of ehp-container is created by the same piece of code for old and new error pages. Problem is, the new background images provided to me are of a different size, so when I try to apply the styling I need to make them look good for the new error pages (background-size: 100% 93%;), that breaks the old error pages, which use a static background-size.

[image]

The options I see:

1. Modify the builder class to add some sort of an additional class to ehp-container that would distinguish the new error pages (less than ideal, hackish)
2. Ask the UX team to for new images that match in size (long turnaround)

Can anyone think of anything else?

Comment: Is the `HTML` markup for both old and new page exactly the same?

Comment: `background-size: cover` doesn't work?

Comment: HTML is the same for the most part yes, everything is the same, the differences are inside ehp-container and CSS doesn't have downward-referencing selectors yet as far as I know

Comment: cover is nice, didn't know about this. but no, doesn't work, cuts part of the image off.

Answer (score 1):

Apply an identifier to an outer container. Do your error pages have a template (e.g. masterpage/layoutpage). If so, does the old one use a different one from the new one?

If so, add a class name or id to an outer container and reference it in your CSS:

```
#newerrorpage-outercontainer .ehp-container {
    /* attributes */
}
```

Alternatively, for the code that generates the error page, update it to accept a cssClass parameter and apply this along side the container class name:

```
.ehp-container.ehp-v2 {
    /* attributes */
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Yeah that's a possible approach. The code that generates the error page and the template are the same for old ones and new ones. Looks like I will have to go the coding route...